# Analysis of coefficients for quickly vanishing analytic vector field

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-operators

Let $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a divergence-free analytic vector field for $n =3$ or $n =4$, i.e., $u_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are analytic functions locally given by

$$u_i(x) = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}_0^n} c_j^{(i)} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{j_k}$$

for some real $c_j^{(i)}$.
Furthermore, we request $$|\partial_x^{\alpha} u(x)| \leq C_{\alpha K}(1+|x|)^{-K}$$
on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $\alpha,K$.

My question is now, can we infer some requirements for the coefficients $c_j^{(i)}$, such that the above conditions are equivalent to these requirements.

Comment: An obvious requirement is implied by Cauchy-Hadamard: $$ \limsup_{j\in\Bbb N_0^n}\sqrt[|j|]{|c_j^{(I)}|}=0.$$ Probably you can see how this restriction works jointly with the derivative growth estimate you’re interested to.

Comment: A few clarifications requested: (a) when you say $u_i$ is analytic, are you assuming necessarily that it has infinite radius of convergence? (Technically $1/(1+x^2)$ is a real analytic function too.) (b) What are the "conditions" in your question? Are you assuming divergence free throughout, or are you looking for a requirement that is equal to "divergence free + rapid decay"?

Comment: I am doubtful you can see decay rates at infinity just from some size estimates on the coefficients. $\cos(x^2)$ and $e^{-x^2}$ have very similar Taylor series.

Comment: @WillieWong a) You are right, I consider all (!) analytic functions that meet the conditions from above. b) The conditions are, analytic, divergence-free everywhere, and the inequalities.